# Batch/pause foreach loop after specified number of returns

Tags: c#, foreach, batch-processing

I have a C# "foreach" loop I would like to run a batch of 100, then pause for a specified period of time. How can I go about batch processing a "foreach" loop? I have tried many examples and all have failed. Here is the code contaning the loop. Thank you very much.

```
foreach (string filename in filenames)
            {

                PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();


                pic.ClientSize = new Size(ThumbWidth, ThumbHeight);
                pic.Image = new Bitmap(filename);

                
                if ((pic.Image.Width > ThumbWidth) ||
                    (pic.Image.Height > ThumbHeight))
                {
                    pic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                }
                else
                {
                    pic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
                }

                
                pic.DoubleClick += PictureBox_DoubleClick;

               
                    FileInfo file_info = new FileInfo(filename);
                    tipPicture.SetToolTip(pic, file_info.Name +
                    "\nCreated: " + file_info.CreationTime.ToShortDateString() +
                    "\n(" + pic.Image.Width + " x " + pic.Image.Height + ") " +
                    ToFileSizeApi(file_info.Length));
                    pic.Tag = file_info;                
                    
                   
                    pic.Parent = flpThumbnails;                   


            }
```

Comment: _I have tried many examples and all have failed_ - can you show examples which are failed and why they failed?

Comment: Honestly it's been about three weeks since I touched the project but I am need to finish it now, but I think I attempted to follow this: [link](https://hjerpbakk.com/blog/2018/03/05/batch-process-ienumerable) and then the application gave me 0 results, I may have implemented it wrong, I don't remember. There were a few more I tried to implement and no luck, I don't remember the pages though. @Fabio

Comment: Sorry, how we can help you if you don't remember why your previous approaches failed. Can you try to reproduce issues you had, please?

Comment: Yes I will try to recreate the code from the best of my recollection and edit my original post and add it. @Fabio

Comment: Have you tried a for loop instead? You can set the max to whatever number you want to stop at. Then maybe put the program on a task scheduler or something?

Comment: No I have not tried that, how would I convert that to a for loop?